# R-Randomize column according to IDs in another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of several columns, say it looks like the following:

```
 ID percent region
 1    5       1
 1    8       2
 1    10      3
 1    100     4
 2    20      1
 2    6       2
 2    9       3
 2    1       4
 3    9       1
 3    78      2
 3    56      3
 3    99      4
 4    1       1
 4    1       2
 4    8       3
```

I need to randomize the "percent" column of the dataset, but the values (and order of the values) need to be the same within the individual's (given by ID) block. The "region" and any other column remains as is, and only "percent" should be randomized. An example can be the following:

```
 ID percent region
 2    20      1
 2    6       2
 2    9       3
 2    1       4
 4    1       1
 4    1       2
 4    8       3
 1    5       1
 1    8       2
 1    10      3
 1    100     4
 3    9       1
 3    78      2
 3    56      3
 3    99      4
```

Note that the order of values within IDs of "percent" remains the same.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for.  It looks like you are randomly permuting the order of the IDs (2 4 1 3 instead of 1 2 3 4) keeping the rows intact.  Am I missing something?

Comment: right, basically i want to keep the every other column the same except the order of percent (but must be the same order within the same ID block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the `distinct` 'ID', `sample` on it, extract the subset of dataset by comparing with each `sample`d 'ID" and bind it together (`map_df`)

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  distinct(ID) %>%
  pull(ID) %>%
  sample %>% 
  map_df(~ df1 %>% filter(ID == .x))
```

Or a faster option would be to `split` by 'ID', then rearrange the `list` elements by `sample`ing on the `names` of the `list` and bind the rows (`bind_rows`)

```
df1 %>%
   split(.$ID) %>%
   .[sample(names(.))] %>%
   bind_rows
```

---

Or we can use `base R` by using the same methodology as above

```
lst <- split(df1, df1$ID)
df2 <- do.call(rbind, lst[sample(names(lst))])
row.names(df2) <- NULL
df2
#    ID percent region
#1   4       1      1
#2   4       1      2
#3   4       8      3
#4   3       9      1
#5   3      78      2
#6   3      56      3
#7   3      99      4
#8   2      20      1
#9   2       6      2
#10  2       9      3
#11  2       1      4
#12  1       5      1
#13  1       8      2
#14  1      10      3
#15  1     100      4
```

Comment: This almost gets me what I want. There is another column that I did not include in my example for simplicity, but I guess I should've included it. When I run your code, it does exactly what I want except one of the columns (not included in my example) also changes. How can I keep all of columns intact (same order) with the exception of ID and percent. Your code is almost there.

Comment: I realize I can simply copy and paste from the original dataset, many thanks